# Build fluent service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, fluent

I have a simple factory in AngularJS:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule', [])
        .factory('myService', service);

    function service(){
        var products= function(p1, p2, p3, ..., pn) {
            var url = "http://something.url/api/action";
            var data = {
                'p1': p1,
                'p2': p2,
                ...
                'pn': pn,
            }

            // return data           
            return $http
                .post(url, data)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }

        return {
            Products : products
        };
    }
})();
```

I use this service inside a controller like this:

```
myInjectedService
    .Products(vm.p1, vm.p1, ... , vm.pn)
    .then(successCallbackFn)
    .catch(failureCallbackFn);
```

Each parameter (`p1`, ..., `pn`) are used to filter the final result. This works like a charm! But with a little drawback: there are to many accepted arguments for `Products` and is really difficult to know if I'm sending the right parameters and this sounds a little error prone. What I would is a fluent API for service that make everything more human readable, this would be great:

```
myInjectedService
    .Products()
    .FilterById(p1)
    .WhereCategoryIs(p2)
    ...
    .WhereSomethingElseIs(pn)
    .Send()
    .then(successCallbackFn)
    .catch(failureCallbackFn);
```

Previously the task of HTTP call was handled by `Products` call. Right now `Products()`, only make an empty query (i.e. `{}`). Each subsequent `FilterByX` will enrich the query (i.e. `{'productId': 'xxx-yyy-1111'}`). Calling `Send()` will make the real HTTP POST call. This call will use the `data` builded through various filter applied. How can I do that? I'm playing with prototype but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archieve what you want by define a new class and use prototype like this.

In a fluent method, remember to return the object itself.

```js
   function service(){
        var products = function(url) {
          
            // Define a new Product class
            var Products = function() {
              this.url = url;
              this.data = {};
            };
            
            // Add the function
            Products.prototype.FilterById = function(id) {
                this.data.id = id;
                // To make it fluent, return the object itself
                return this;
            };
              
            Products.prototype.FilterByCategory = function(category) {
                this.data.category = category;
                return this;
            };
              
            Products.prototype.send = function() {
               console.log(this.data);
            };
              
            // Return an instance of the Products class
            return new Products();
          };
      
        return {
            Products : products
        };
   };
   
 service().Products().FilterById(1).FilterByCategory("Item").send();
```

You can read more about it here: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-like-boss-understanding-fluent-apis/

Comment: The `Products` class could be declared outside the `products` method, but still inside service function, so that it is not declared each time `Products()` is called.